# Text input value is disappearing Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I type a text and hit 'ok' or click the back button to hide the keyboard the input's value vanishes

Adding a TextEditingController

```dart
class ChatCepBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {

  final TextEditingController _cepController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: _cepController,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 32),
        Button(
          buttonText: 'Search',
          tapHandler: () {},
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I expected that the typed text staid in the text controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of the "Button" is wrong. Check the [Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material#Buttons) for more information. Plus, you can't preserve the state in a `StatelessWidget`.

This will help:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final TextEditingController _cepController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: _cepController,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 32),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Search'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry for that

Answer (score 8):

When keyboard opens it changes the screen behavior and when we close it it re renders the screen and due to that this field initialized again by empty constructor.

```
 TextEditingController _cepController = TextEditingController();
```

Stateful or stateless it doesnt matter if you are in this kind of issue like keyboard opening etc
try defining `final TextEditingController _cepController = TextEditingController();` outside of this class

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do will not work with Flutter. You are using a `stateless` widget and trying to preserve state (data), which is impossible by definition. You need to rewrite your class using a `stateful` widget - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html.

See an example below:

`````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatCepBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatCepBottomSheetState createState() => _ChatCepBottomSheetState();
}

class _ChatCepBottomSheetState extends State<ChatCepBottomSheet> {
  final TextEditingController _cepController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: _cepController,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 32),
        Button( //choose a button class or custom class
          buttonText: 'Search',
          tapHandler: () {},
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Not sure this is the solution, as other answers above have already proposed a solution, but what worked for me was; Removing the ***texteditingcontroller*** and using an ***onChanged*** instead